# Google Maps V3 - How Do I Change Markers to Custom Icons for Each Location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the Google Maps Api v3 example here for "Complex Marker Icons" - Which only shows 1 icon for all locations

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex

I'm a Javascript newbie, how do I change the icons to a different icons (custom) for each location?

I've read thru other q's about this, but still confused. If you can explain to make the changes for the above example, that would be great. I'm trying to create a map based off of that example.

btw - this is just for desktop version, not concern with mobile at this time.

Comment: [one example with several markers](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_markers_colored.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you're loading data from geojson file then you will have Data class (which is where you play with the layer of geospatial data) check out the [latest exp api reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data)

Now with the latest experimental version, you can use setStyle() with a function to load different icons as per a property defined in each point.

Variable map is where you defined your Google map container and map options. Then you can use setStyle as follows:

```
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
  return {
  icon: 'http://URLTOYOURICON/' + feature.getProperty('PROPERTYNAME') + '.png',
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The parts you need to focus on are the creation of the image object

```
  var image = {
    url: 'images/beachflag.png',
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  };
```

and the creation of the marker object

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        shadow: shadow,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: beach[0],
        zIndex: beach[3]
    });
```

Notice, the marker object are created in a for loop and each marker uses the exact same image object (as defined above).  The image object is assigned to the `icon` property.

You can create a bunch of different image objects.  This particular one points to "beachflag.png".  You can have many different image objects that point to different images.

I would recommend storing them all in an array for easy access.

Then when you create the marker, you can add the logic to change the `icon` property of the marker to use any of the image objects that you created.

Conversely, you can create image objects on the fly at the moment that you create the marker.  Such as.

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        shadow: shadow,
        icon: {
            url: beach[4],
            // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
            size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
            // The origin for this image is 0,0.
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
        };,
        shape: shape,
        title: beach[0],
        zIndex: beach[3]
    });
```

Comment: I tried adding the icon image to the current arrayvar beaches = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4, icon1.png],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5, icon2.png],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3, icon3.png],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2, icon4.png],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1, icon5.png]
]; But didn't work, do I need to declare the icon slot in the array?

Comment: What array are you talking about?

Comment: If you're going to do that, then you have to call the beach[4] element of the array.  I edited the second example in my answer to reflect this.  note that the icon needs to be the path if it's not in the same directory as the webpage file.

Comment: thnx, I will play with that.